# Flutter-I was creating a cart for my eccomerce app and want to shift products from cart collection to orders collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any command to rename the collection or move documents from one collection to other in firestore through flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in command or operation to rename a collection of move documents.

You will have to build this yourself, based upon the [existing API](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore-class.html), typically by first reading the documents from the source, then writing them to the destination, and finally deleting them fro the source. If you need the operation to be atomic, you'll want to do all of this [using one or more transactions](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#transactions).